# Is there a way to load ionic pages inside of an ionic segment?

Tags: ionic3, ion-segment

A newbie with ionic v3. I have three ionic pages which i am trying to display inside of ionic segments. I want to keep the functionality of the pages segregated for easier maintainability. For now i haven't found a workaround since ionic won't allow more than one ion-content in a page. Any other approach/suggestions/workarounds?

I Have tried setting the pages as tabRoots and invoking them in the segment page

The three pages look like:

```
<ion-content padding>
page design and api calls etc..
</ion-content>
```

The main page for displaying the tabs looks like:
manage-request.html

```
<app-header heading="Manage Requests"></app-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="relationship" color="primary">
  <ion-segment-button text-center value="travelrequest"[root]="tab1Root">
Travel Request
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="approverequest" [root]="tab2Root">
    Approve Request
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="approveexception" [root]="tab3Root">
    Approve Exception
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
</ion-content>
<app-footer isCheckStatus="true"></app-footer>
```

manage-request.ts

```
    export class ManageRequestPage{
    @ViewChild("manageTabs") manageTabs: Tabs;
    tab1Root = TravelRequestPage;t
    tab2Root = ApproveRequestPage;
    tab3Root = ApproveExceptionRequestPage;
}
```

Expected result:
contents of the pages are displayed when i switch the tabs of the ionic segments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered putting your "page" functionality into an angular component (not a full-blown Ionic "page")?  In my experience an Ionic "page" is treated differently and likely isn't meant for having many displayed at once, especially if you are using [IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).  The simple CLI command below will generate a component.  Then put your UI/Logic in there, and put that element in your `ion-segment`.

```
ionic generate component
```

[Here is a quick example I whipped up on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fcsgbu?embed=1).  Notice there are 3 segments on the home page, and the middle one (bookmark) has a component in it.

Comment: thanks @BRass . I thought of doing the same today but i am stuck at how the segment will go about loading the components since it throws an error saying:

`Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-segment-button'.`

also tried with just [root] instead of tabRoot. Same error.

Can you maybe whip up a small example to show how you'd approach this?
Also, big thanks for helping out a noob mate!

Comment: I threw a quick example link above.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use ngSwitch like this `[ngSwitch]="mySegment"`, so you don't need to use `tabRoot` and more than one `ion-content` for switch the tabs.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title> Manage Requests </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>

<ion-list-header text-center>

<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="mySegment" (ionChange)="segmentChanged(mySegment)">
  <ion-segment-button value="travelrequest">
      <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="approverequest">
      <ion-icon name="ios-checkmark"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="approveexception">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

</ion-list-header>

<div [ngSwitch]="mySegment">

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'travelrequest'">
    <ion-item>
        <p> Here is the travelrequest content… </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'approverequest'">
    <ion-item>
        <p> Here is the approverequest content… </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'approveexception'">
    <ion-item>
        <p> Here is the approveexception content… </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</div>

</ion-content>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't want the content to be loading from inside the same page that contains the segment. since each of those will be near about 150-200 lines of code. its better to keep them in separate pages.
I have had minor success using this:

 `<ion-tabs #manageTabs (ionChange)="tabSelected($event)" [selectedIndex]="tabsIndex">
        <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"  tabTitle="Travel Request"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Approve Request"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Approve Exception"></ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>`

But i wanna do it with segments

Comment: Ahh okay! So I think a good approach for you could be [SuperTabs](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs) not the Segment component.

Comment: I am sort of trying to refrain from third party packages but thanks for the suggestion @Everton Costa !